# How to move the image from one place to other place through touch listener?

Tags: android, android-widget

There is one image on LinearLayout. I have to move that image in any direction by touch. Please help me how to do.

Comment: whcih android version ur using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use example as http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/drag-and-drop-ui-element/  or http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html

and if you are using  version 3.0 higher than it than use example as given at http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: Hi Khan, how to change the position of that button depending on the motion of finger touch? Please Help me.